# Joomla 2.5 component. Non blocking modal before saving

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, joomla

In a custom component I have a .js file with an ajax call that simply pass a POST Json.
An API file which get the posted Json and do some checkings.
I'd like to prevent the default behaviour of Joomla toolbar, like if I click save, an ajax (depending on some conditions) call send a post to the API, and depending on the response fire a non blocking modal with Cancel/Go ahead button.
I wondering if there's a way to intercept the Joomla toolbar save/save and close action event.

I guess the trick is how joomla save button works... `JToolBarHelper::apply('myTask');`

Any hint would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your button has an onclick event handler you could simply override that in your component js file. For example the content component 'apply' button has the below event handler:-

onclick="Joomla.submitbutton('article.apply')"

As long as you load your .js file last you can make a copy of the Joomla.submitbutton function and handle the click event however you like.

For example:

```
    /* Fires on occasion when a button has it bound to it's onclick event */
    Joomla.submitbutton = function(task)
    {

      // Do AJAX request here
      ...
      // Trigger modal here etc 

      return false;
    }
```

You should be able to prevent the default save action that way simply by return false at the end which will prevent the click event propagating.

Comment: Ok, I managed how to load my.js after Joomla's core.js and mootools-more.js
Then I tried :
Joomla.submitbutton = function(task)
 {
  // Trigger modal here etc
  if (task == 'agencies.mytaskupdate' || task == 'agencies.mytaskclose')
  {
   // Do AJAX request here
   console.log('checking');
  }

  else
   Joomla.submitform(task);

  return false;
 }
No console log and still behave as usual though. Seems I miss something here?

Comment: What happens if you just put Joomla.submitbutton = function(task){ alert('submit') } - do you get an alert? If not then either your script file isn't loading or it's not loaded last.

Comment: My bad, the hint was right, solved my issue. Thanks Adam :)